# Understanding string encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm stuck in a very awkward situation where my JS developer left without notice and he used some kind of string encryption (which I had asked him to do) that I can't find over internet. I have the decrypt function but not the encrypt function. I don't know how he did it.

Here is the decrypt function:

```
function decryptFunct(string1, string2) 
{
            var var1, var2 = "";
            for (var1 = 0; var1 < string1.length; var1 += 2) var2 += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(string1.substring(var1, var1 + 2), 16));
            var1 = var2;
            var var2 = [],
                var3 = 0, 
                var4 = 0, 
                var5 = 0, 
                var6 = 0,
                var7 = "";
            for (var3 = 0; var3 < 256; var3++) var2[var3] = var3;
            for (var3 = 0; var3 < 256; var3++) var6 = (var6 + var2[var3] + string2.charCodeAt(var3 % string2.length)) % 256, var4 = var2[var3], var2[var3] = var2[var6], var2[var6] = var4;
            for (var5 = var3 = var6 = 0; var5 < var1.length; var5++) var3 = (var3 + 1) % 256, var6 = (var6 + var2[var3]) % 256, var4 = var2[var3], var2[var3] = var2[var6], var2[var6] = var4, var7 += String.fromCharCode(var1.charCodeAt(var5) ^ var2[(var2[var3] + var2[var6]) % 256]);
            return var7;
}

key = "08144e3d408376b";
decryptFunct("685gf7195fb7", key);
```

I'm not expecting to solve this completely, I know it's very hard.

Comment: If it's an impossible stuff then I'll close this as somebody voted it for 'close'.

Comment: If it worked before, there definitely is a way to do it. The problem is that if it's some "custom" (i.e. bad) encryption function, it's going to take time to figure it out, which isn't really useful information to anyone besides you.

Comment: Yes right, what would you suggest?

Comment: Either pay someone to do it or do it yourself.

Comment: I think I should hire a freelancer who can solve this. Thanks for your interest because I can't. ;) I'm closing/deleting this one as I think it won't help anyone other than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I figured it out. It is rc4 stream encryption.